# What data structure are practical for spiderweb-like structures

Tags: javascript, data-structures, p5.js

I'm creating a program that generates miniature cities.

My first step was to create the streets of the city (represented with lines). In order to do so I created a street class which grows and gives birth to smaller streets recursively. The streets then stop growing as soon as they hit another street or the edge of the world. It looks like this :

[image]

As a second step I'd like to extrude on a z-axis all the polygons encapsulated by the streets, though I'm having a hard time finding the coordinates of these polygons easily.

Does anyone know of a data strcuture that I could rewrite my program with that would make accessing the polygons coordinates easily ? I've tried to implement a half-edge data structure but it really seems like overkill.

Comment: You should post a minimal code snippet so it's easier for other to provide feedback that is more atuned to your approach. Without seeing your code I can only make assumptions such as a recursive function that returns no point data back and simply renders lines. In a general sense I would imagine a graph (where street corners are vertices and streets are edges) could work. Wether this would be directed vs undirected, cyclical vs acyclical, etc. depends on what you plan to do next. If you want to extrude in 3D a half-edge data structure would be handy (and there are libraries to help with this)